# Writing non-indentation sensitive code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

(I am a beginner) Python normally uses indentation to specify the nesting level of code lines. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Your question lacks actual code, -1. **Show us your code.**

Comment: @ulidtko What code do you expect him to show?

Comment: @Paul any one, which he has troubles with. That way we could argue by example.

Comment: @ulidtko It doesn't apply here.

Comment: Also, not providing any problematic code for a question displays lack of effort from the asker. Questions without code are less useful, in general.

Comment: [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086/is-there-a-way-around-coding-in-python-without-the-tab-indent-whitespace-crit) was asked long ago, to be fair.

Comment: @Paul, it easily does. For example, imagine a badly indented C++ snippet being asked for a rough Python translation.

Comment: What about replacing indentation with a nesting level number for each line?

Comment: @LinuxDistance: Seriously? You think starting each line with a nesting level number is **better** than simply starting each line with that number of indentation levels?!?!?!?! That is crazier than adding braces (or begin..end) to Python!

Answer (score 11):

No, the Python developers are very resistant to this, as it would mean changing one of the core foundations on which Python was based. Just try `from __future__ import braces`.

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance (<pyshell#30>, line 1)
```

Indeed, "not a chance" :-)

Comment: I know that brackets for code blocks will not be implemented, but is there any way other than indentation or braces to define code blocks or instead I will end up writing very complicated code.

Comment: @LinuxDistance What other way could there be? And how can this effect the complexity of your code?

Comment: @LinuxDistance Your code isn't going to be bad because of indentation. If you think that's the case then you need to take a serious look at how your code is organized.

Comment: @arshajii: There is a third way.  In ruby and vbscript many constructs (looping, if statements, function definitions, etc) effectively act as an opening brace that needs to be explicitly ended with a keyword (such as `end`, `End If`, `End Sub`).  I initially thought of this as a variant on braces, but the implicit "opening brace" makes it different.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes you are right, I forgot about that variant. Nevertheless, there's really only one way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The core design philosophy behind Python is human readability; indentation is used to specify code blocks because visually, this is significantly cleaner than the use of braces.

For more info, see [PEP 20 - The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 0):

Until I find that thing I glanced at a while ago, a pointer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation) is going to have to suffice as an answer: consider using `reindent.py` to fix your indents after writing the code however you want.

Pick it up from [this site](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py).